# Mysql Join query with date grouping

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table which contains date field, now I am looking for a query to group the records by date and then give me data under each date,

row 1- 2019-03-01

```
row1.1 - record (matching to date 2019-03-01)
row1.2 - 
row1.3
```

row 2 - 2019-03-02

```
row 2.1
row 2.2
row 2.3
row 2.4
```

table structure

```
id  tbdate  status
=====================
1   2019-03-01  active
2   2019-02-01  active
3   2019-03-02  active
4   2019-03-01  inactive
5   2019-03-03  active
```

Comment: For me it looks like you do not need grouping. You need just order results by date.

Comment: i need grouping to get all unique dates and then results within those unique dates. hence grouping will be required.

Comment: It is not grouping in terms of SQL. If you order by date all records that belong to the date will be together. It is some kind of 'grouping'.

Comment: I am not sure how to write the SQL query on this just with order by, expected results are date and results. I will be okay to even get results like below

2019-03-01 1,4
2019-03-03 5
2019-02-01 2

Comment: Maybe you could upload a photo of your example desired output?

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1):

you just need order by in your query, not grouping as per your requirement

```
select * 
from table_name
order by tbdate;
```

and for mysql 8.0

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbdate,ORDER BY tbdate) AS id
from table_name;
```

Comment: hi i need data i below format 

row 1- 2019-03-01 (1st row) as I need to first show date and then results of that date below it, then next date and results matching date.

 row1.1 - record (matching to date 2019-03-01)
 row1.2 - 
 row1.3

row 2 - 2019-03-02
 row 2.1
 row 2.2
 row 2.3
 row 2.4

Comment: it's not possible as you asking non structural query as you want 1 date column and then entire record data of that below it.

Comment: is it possible to have the sub rows as a new column with values comma separated ?

Comment: that's the group_concat your query answer :                                                                           (SELECT tbdate  ,GROUP_CONCAT(status) FROM table_name
GROUP BY tbdate)